# Add background image to navigation in .net maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I would like to make a background image spread across the entire screen, and make the pages navigated to, display as a block in the center. Currently the background image code I have is not working and I'm unsure of how to go about displaying the other pages in a block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="Nova.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nova"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Nova.View"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Locked"
     BackgroundImageSource="Assets/BackgroundImage.png">

    <!--<ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />-->

    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <Image Source="Assets/logo.png" HeightRequest="152"></Image>
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>


    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <Label Text="Username" Padding="20"></Label>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Dashboard" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Dashboard"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DashboardPage}"/>
        </Tab>

    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Clients" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Clients"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ClientListPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Staff" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Staff"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:StaffListPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Projects" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Projects"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProjectsPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="Finances" Icon="dotnet_bot.png">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent 
                Title="Finances"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FundsPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>


</Shell>
```

Comment: Can you show what your result currently looks like and also show what you would like it to look like?

Comment: pages take up the entire screen (or window).  If you want the page content as a centered block, you will need to add padding to the page.  Likewise, you would set the background image on the page, not in the "navigation"

Comment: This is what I want it to look like:
https://www.figma.com/file/CcA8gyVvAQ2CKNlWPMbVQ1/Untitled?type=design&node-id=0%3A1&mode=design&t=f8EkqfuAgxdGTLx0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do does not fit with `Shell`s design. Nor any other navigation scheme (such as `NavigationPage`); app navigation is done "page to page", and a page fills the screen.

Instead, create a single page. Inside it, have a [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview). Change that `ContentView` to point to (contain) different content.

In `App.xaml.cs`, change line:

```cs
MainPage = new AppShell();
```

to:

```cs
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

Where `MainPage.xaml` is something like:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
    x:Class="MyProject.MainPage">

  <!-- numbers control the area surrounding the "middle area" -->
  <Grid RowDefinitions="50,*,50" ColumnDefinitions="50,*,50">

    <!-- covers the whole screen -->
    <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Source=... />

    <!-- "middle area". It is "on top of" backgroundImage -->
    <ContentView x:Name="content" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    content.Content = new MyView1();
  }

  public void GoView2()
  {
    content.Content = new MyView2();
  }
}
```

MyView1.xaml:

```
<ContentView ...
    x:Class="MyProject.MyView1" />
  ...
</ContentView>
```

etc.

NOTE: `MyView1` (etc.) don't have to be `ContentView`. Each can be any layout class, such as `Grid` or `VerticalStackLayout`.

---

---

**OPTIONAL: To re-use views, use Service Provider instead of `new MyView1()`**

See section "AppServiceProvider: USE SERVICE PROVIDER TO AVOID "new MyPage();"" of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741424/199364.

As you become more familiar with Maui, you will see many suggestions to use [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/dependency-injection).

I've answered the question using `content.Content = new MyView1();`, because that is easier to understand, and get started with.

Applying the answer-section linked above, change this to:

```cs
content.Content = AppServiceProvider.GetService<MyView1>();
```

That section shows other coding you need to do, to make use of this technique.

I won't discuss here why you might want to do this.
Don't worry about this yet. Get `new MyView1()` working first.

Comment: Thank you so much! My only problem is that when I click on one of the views, the navigation doesn't appear - so i don't think the grid is working.

Comment: Add an UPDATED section to answer, showing your revised code.

Comment: Hi! So this ended up working perfectly! However, how would I navigate to the other pages from within another page. For example there is a button in the dashboard to navigate you to the staff page.

Comment: In Staff's ShellContent, add `Route="Staff"` (name as desired). To go: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Staff");`. If doesn't work, add UPDATE section to question, showing XAML you now have for that ShellContent. And the complete declaration of method in which you do that goto (including the goto line). Also put a note here alerting me to your change.