# Prism.Maui - Pages not being disposed when calling _navigationService.GoBackToRootAsync()

Tags: .net, maui

Our App uses Prism.Maui, we seem to be having an issue regarding pages not being disposed when calling NavigationService.GoBackToRootAsync().

`public static class PageLoader
{

```
    private static INavigationService _navigationService => ApplicationState.PrismContainer.GetService<INavigationService>();

    public static async void StartAtHomeOrLogin(bool isLoggedIn)
    {
        if (isLoggedIn)
            BuildTabs<DashboardViewModel>();
        else
        {
            await _navigationService.GoBackToRootAsync();
            ApplicationState.NavigationBuilder = _navigationService.CreateBuilder()
                .AddSegment<LoginViewModel>();
            await ApplicationState.NavigationBuilder.NavigateAsync();
        }
    }

    // Other methods
```

}`

[The visual tree with duplicate instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlVyV.png)

We have tried various different approaches, from attempting to use the standard .NET MAUI NavigationProxy, as well as not using the INavigationBuilder and just using NavigationService, however due to our specific setup, we need to use the INavigationBuilder to support our TabbedPage setup as Prism.Maui docs advise strongly against manually setting up Tabs in the TabbedPage.

So is summary we need to still use the INavigationBuilder approach, but before setting ApplicationState.NavigationBuilder to a new instance by calling _navigationService.CreateBuilder(), and navigating, we need to ensure the current stack is popped.

Comment: I thought pages were not even disposed of in Xamarin. GC decides when to dispose, they aren't disposed of manually, and that actually even makes sense to be frank there is no need to manually dispose of pages, and will add additional overhead to go back the whole stack of items and dispose of them one after the other. Is there a particular reason you want this?

Comment: There is a previous StackOverflow post where the person did tests and concluded that page dispose is NEVER called. Not ever. For any page in Maui. I have not confirmed this, but if true, then something under the hood in Maui is holding on to page references. Maui devs need to find that, change it to a weak reference. For now, all pages should be defined SINGLETON (not TRANSIENT). Manually write code that restores the page to a clean state whenever it is displayed. This is easiest if it is all called by Bindings. See if page's OnAppearing and OnDisappearing are being called.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76739030/199364 and https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7354.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. It seems like you are not familiar with the standards of Stack Overflow regarding questions. Please read following article: [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option.