# How to create a PageHandler to display a UITableViewController in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have binded a native iOS SDK to use it in MAUI.

This SDK provides a method that returns a UITableViewController.

I try to create a PageHandler to transform this native iOS UITableViewController to a MAUI Page so I can use it in my app.

Here is the code of the MAUI Page :

```cs
public class SignatureSettingsPage : Page
{
    public SignatureSettingsPage()
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my PageHandler in Platforms.iOS :

```cs
public class SignatureSettingsPageHandler : PageHandler
{
    UITableViewController NativeUITableViewController;

    public void SetNativeUITableViewController(UITableViewController controller)
    {
        this.NativeUITableViewController = controller;
    }

    protected override Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView CreatePlatformView()
    {
        _ = VirtualView ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(VirtualView)} must be set to create a LayoutView");
        _ = MauiContext ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(MauiContext)}} cannot be null");

        if (ViewController == null)
            ViewController = this.NativeUITableViewController;

        if (ViewController is PageViewController pc && pc.CurrentPlatformView is Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView pv)
            return pv;

        if (ViewController.View is Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView cv)
            return cv;

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"NativeUITableViewController.View must be a {nameof(Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView)}");
    }
}
```

And here is the code in Platforms.iOS that get the controller from the binded SDK and which create the MAUI Page :

```cs
public SignatureSettingsPage GetSignatureSettingsPage()
{
    UITableViewController nativeController = NativeSDK.GetUITableViewController();

    SignatureSettingsPageHandler mauiHandler = new SignatureSettingsPageHandler();
    mauiHandler.SetNativeUITableViewController(nativeController);

    SignatureSettingsPage mauiPage = new SignatureSettingsPage();
    mauiPage.Handler = mauiHandler;

    return mauiPage;
}
```

Unfortunately, I get errors in the CreatePlatformView() method from the PageHandler :
VirtualView throw a InvalidCastException :

```
    System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.IContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentView, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].get_VirtualView()
```

And if I comment the two verifications of VirtualView and MauiContext, the method don't return and throw the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: NativeUITableViewController.View must be a ContentView
```

I verified the NativeSDK.GetUITableViewController() does not return null, the controller looks good.

Also, the MauiContext is null in CreatePlatformView().

I think I did not write the PageHandler correctly..

Any help please ?

Comment: *"MauiContext is null "*. Test it by changing your `App.xaml.cs`. Replace `MainPage = new Shell();` with `MainPage = new MyPageNameHere();`. Once you get that working (I can't help with that), search for other StackOverflow posts for discussion of problems with app startup. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/76815117/199364 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438903/how-can-i-resolve-a-service-that-i-registered-with-the-builder-services-inside-o/76547442 or

Comment: Should we apply a handler after ```MainPage = new MyPageNameHere();``` ?

Comment: Hmm. I need to see all the code. Make a public gitbhub repo with a solution that can be run. Just enough code to cause the symptom. Link that here. MauiContext null means that startup has not gotten to the correct state yet. Need to move around some code, but I'm not sure yet exactly how.